# Html Helper does not contain a definition for Highsoft

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm using asp.net mvc for develop simple web apllication,add this package to my nuget:

```
highsoft.web.mvc version 5.0.10.1
```

and try to add chart to view page:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


            @(Html.Highsoft().GetHighcharts(
        new Highcharts
        {
            Chart = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Chart
            {
                PlotBackgroundColor = null,
                PlotBorderWidth = null,
                PlotShadow = new Shadow
                {
                    Enabled = false
                }
            },
            Title = new Title
            {
                Text = "Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014"
            },
            Tooltip = new Tooltip
            {
                PointFormat = "{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>"
            },
            PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = PlotOptionsPieCursor.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Format = "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %"
                    }
                }
            },
            Series = new List<Series>
            {
                new PieSeries
                {
                    Name = "Browser Share",
                    Data = @ViewData["pieData"] as List<PieSeriesData>
                },

            }
        }
        , "chart")
            )
```

but in this line:

```
@(Html.Highsoft().GetHighcharts(
```

get this error:

> Html Helper does not contain a definition for Highsoft

How can i solve that problem?thanks.
a complete error message:

> CS1929: 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
>   'Highsoft' and the best extension method overload
>   'HtmlHelperExtensions.Highsoft(IHtmlHelper)' requires a receiver of
>   type 'IHtmlHelper'

Comment: Have you added a `@using` in the view for Highsoft (or added it to the `webconfig` file)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for answer,which web config?

Comment: @StephenMuecke in view add this using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts

Comment: @StephenMuecke i add it complete error message ,please review my question

Comment: Adding `@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts` in the beginning of the view file should solve this problem. Could you provide the whole project so that I can inspect that?